# Handling multiple Rest Services in ACTIVITI Process

Tags: spring, activiti

I am completely new to Spring and Activiti, and made myself a little Project which works just fine. there are 4 service tasks, a REST controller, 1 process, 1 service and 4 methods in this service.

When i call the server endpoint, i start my process and it just goes step by step through my service tasks and calls service.method as defined in the expression ${service.myMethod()}.

BUT, what i really need is a workflow that stops after a servicecall and waits till there is another request sent, similar to a user task waiting for input, the whole process should pause till i send a request to another endpoint.

like myurl:8080/startprocess, and maybe the next day myurl:8080/continueprocess. Maybe even save some data for continued use.

is there a simple predefined way to do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use human tasks for that or use a "signal intermediate catching event" (see activiti´s user guide) after each ativity.

When you do that, the first rest call will start a new process instance that will execute your flow´s activities until it reaches a the signal element. When this happens, the engine saves its current state and returns control to the caller.

In order to make you flow progress, you have to send it a "signal", something you can do with an API call or using the rest API (see item 15.6.2 in the guide)

Comment: nevermind i defined a "signal intermediate catching event" with a "messageEventDefinition" and it works now. thx a lot!